# How do I update a Dynamically Linked Busybox in initramfs.cpio?

Tags: embedded-linux, busybox

I am trying to properly place a Dynamically Linked Busybox into a initramfs.cpio file. I am trying to add udhcpd server to Busybox which was not included in the built image. Then I am placing the updated version into my initramfs.cpio to be compiled into my linux kernal. I can not figure out which files to add in and where to place them. The initramfs.cpio file in the board's stock image doesn't have many libraries included.

I can compile the board's linux with their source files, update the sd card, and run the recompiled kernel. They have some extra modules for their board that are needed.

I have the correct cross compiler set up and can compile the busybox with or without the added packages I want.

I figured out how to pack

```
find . -depth -print | cpio -ov > ../initramfs.cpio
```

and unpack the cpio

```
cpio -idv < initramfs.cpio
```

The unpacked stock cpio looks like this

```
- bin
    + busybox
    + cat2
- cgi_bin
    + cmd
    + download
    + index.cgi
    + mac
    + reboot
    + upload
- dev (empty directory)
- mnt (empty directory)
- proc (empty directory)
- sbin
    + bin2coe
    + dns-sd
    + load_fpga
    + mdnsd.bz2
    + sdctl
    + spiflashctl
    + strace.bz2
    + tshwctl
    + xuartctl
- slib
    + ld-uClibc.so.0
    + libc.so.0
    + libdns_sd.so
    + libutil.so.0
- sys (empty directory)
- tmp (empty directory)
- var
    - run (empty directory)
```

**Busybox Settings:**

```
Cross Compiler Prefix:
/opt/toolchains/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi-

Path to sysroot:
/opt/toolchains/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot
```

**Busybox Bin info:**

```
readelf -d _install/bin/busybox

Tag |  Type    | Name/Value  
0x01| (NEEDED) | Shared Library: [libc.so.0]   
0x0F| (RPATH)  | Library rpath: [/slib]
```

**What I have done:**

Attempt 1
After running make install for busybox, I copied the busybox binary from _install/bin to my unpacked cpio directory test/bin. I packed up the cpio, and then made the kernel with the new initramfs.cpio. I then ran the sd card with the new build. **Fails**

Attempt 2
I copied the following libraries from 
/opt/toolchains/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi/arm-ts-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/

```
+ ld-uClibc.so.0
+ libc.so.0
+ libutil.so.0
```

and pasted them into my unpacked cpio directory test/slib
Then I placed the binary from the original source, and then one from my busybox build in _install/bin, each in separate builds. Each build did not run correctly. **Fails**

I am out of ideas.
Everyone seems to statically link it in their guides, but I have about 4MB for my zImage, and it ends up being too big for that.

Comment: *"Replacing the libraries in slib with ones from the cross compiler's sysroot libraries."* -- That's a vague description.  Have you actually examined your new **busybox** executable for its dependencies?  `readelf -d busybox` will provide pretty output, but I prefer to use `strings busybox | less` because the first line is the name of the loader/linker with a full path (i.e. it might not be /slib/...).   BTW it's not *"folder"*, but directory.

Comment: @sawdust, I updated my question. I showed a portion of the output from `readelf -d _install/bin/busybox`. I looked at the dependencies before, but I only saw the one as stated in the output from your suggested command. All instances of _"folder"_ have been changed to _"directory"_ to reflect proper naming convention.